# Бот aiogram не отвечает на запрос.Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, бот, sendmessage

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]не отвечает на сообщение, подскажите пожалуйста что тут не так)
Мне нужно чтобы бот принимал значение сообщения которое я ему отправляю, принимать его и передавать в зарос к pymysql, и выводить его результат собственно пользователю

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardButton,InlineKeyboardMarkup
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup

import sys
importlib.reload(sys)


# log level
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)


# DB CONNECT
class Test(StatesGroup):
    Q1 = State()
    Q2 = State()

bot = Bot(token=config.API_TOKEN)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage == storage)

try:
    db = pymysql.connect(
        host="",
        port=,
        user="",
        password="",
        database="",

    )
    print("Successfull")

except Exception as ex:
    print("HUINYA")




# Поиск id 
@dp.message_handler(commands="id")
async def welcam (message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите телеграм id пользователя для поиска в базе:")
    await Test.Q2.set()
    @dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'], state=Test.Q2)
    async def idSearch(message: types.Message):
        await message.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ожидайте пару секунд. Идёт поиск...')
        cursor = db.cursor(buffered=True)
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM pussy WHERE id = %s",(message.text,))
        db.commit()

        data = cursor.fetchone()

        if data is None:
                await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Данные не найдены. Попробуй /login')
                await state.finish()


# run long-polling
if __name__ == '__main__':
 executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во первых у Вас отсутвует `except` после `try` что должно само по себе вызывать ошибку. А во вторых что Вам должен отвечать бот если вы не написали что он должен отвечать? Я не вижу у вас функция для ответа бота

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы бот принимал значение сообщения которое я ему отправляю, принимать его и передавать в зарос к pymysql, и выводить его собственно пользователю

Comment: добавьте свою ошибку в попытке сделать эту реализацию и я попробую помочь Вам